# Connecting PhpMyAdmin to AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, xampp, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect my XAMPP installation of PhpMyAdmin to my AWS RDS instance. I made the following configurations to : config.inc.php:

```
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'admin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '*****';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '*******.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Everything works fine in that PhpMyAdmin does pick it up from the dropdown list. But when i select the connection it takes forever and eventually gives the following error(I have checked security grps and it allows all traffic. Is there a way of verifying my logins and security groups):

```
MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Comment: go to xampp console and try using command "mysql -h rdshosthere -u username -p"  .. replace host and username

Comment: no response. should i cd to any particular directory to run the command?

Comment: mysql is working through command line...right?

Comment: its clear that error from rds side...before that you need to confirm it...that's why told to check ..

Comment: I am not sure i understand. your suggestion doesnt  yield a response so im not sure how to interpret that. Please be more specific on how to check for mysql on cmd line

Comment: open xampp window...open shell ... try that mysql command

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: Someone here refers to the VPC settings of the EC2 instance and whitelisting the RDS instance. If you understand please help elaborate. im new to AWS

Comment: are you using any private VPC VPN?

Comment: Im really not sure how to check that. I am new to AWS

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/08/how-to-enable-amazon-rds-remote-access/

Comment: The UI is a little outdated so im following this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxFZt8MG2ss

im just curious how to add a rule for this phpmyadmin, is it all tcp?

Comment: After adding my desktop IP address im now able to connect to it although with some errors:



The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there. -

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'102.165.203.230' (using password: NO) - 

The secret passphrase in configuration (blowfish_secret) is too short.

Answer (score 2):

This worked after adding new rule of my desktop IP to RDS instance. This video takes you through the troubleshooting steps:

youtube.com/watch?v=PxFZt8MG2ss

Comment: The video is very helpful, thanks so much